# Solving $f(x) - g(x) = 0$, where $f(x) = e^x - 2.4$ and the graph of $g(x)$ is shown

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing a practice test for my EOC which is coming up soon and I can't solve this (and I don't know what to search). How can I solve this?

Solve $f(x) - g(x) = 0$, to the nearest tenth, where $f(x) = e^x - 2.4$ and $g(x)$ is shown.

[image: function_graph]

Comment: you would do better posting the question here, instead of linking to a picture. I, for example, cannot open the picture you posted because of server restriction rules -- but would be able to read the text had you posted it directly.

Comment: @gt6989b : Unfortunately, this is an "interpret this graph" problem, so you have to see the image.  However, ryan doherty, it would have been helpful to post the *text* here.

Comment: I can't easily copy and paste the question due to the way the site is setup.

Comment: It's one line of text with a couple of equations...

Comment: I posted the text and a link to the picture of the graph on my GDrive

Comment: Can you post a Screenshot?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to solve for g(x), which is a piecewise function.

$g(x)=$
\begin{array}{ll}
      ax^2+bx+c & x < 2 \\
      -1 & x\geq 2 \\
\end{array}

Plug $g(0)=0,g(2)=4$ into $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, we get $c=0,b=0,a=1$.

So, $g(x)=$
\begin{array}{ll}
      x^2 & x < 2 \\
      -1 & x\geq 2 \\
\end{array}

Next, solve for $f(x)=g(x)$.

When $x<2$, $f(x)=g(x) \Rightarrow$ $e^x-2.4=x^2$ $\Rightarrow e^x-x^2-2.4=0$

Here, I suggest using bisection method. Let $h(x)=e^x-x^2-2.4$. e is approximately 2.72

Choose upper bound $u=2$, lower bond $l=1$.

$h(1)=2.72-1-2.4=-0.68<0$ and $h(2)=2.72^2-2^2-2.4=0.9984>0$, so we set the middle point $m=(1+2)/2=1.5$

$h(1.5)=2.72^{1.5}-1.5^2-2.4=-0.164<0$, so we set the new lower bound $l=1.5$ and the new middle point $m=(1.5+2)/2=1.75$

$h(1.75)=2.72^{1.75}-1.75^2-2.4=0.298>0$, so we set the new upper bound $u=1.75$ and the new middle point $m=(1.5+1.75)/2=1.625$

So you get $x=1.6$

When $x\geq2$, $e^x-2.4=-1$. You can use the similar method, and get $x=0.3$, which contradicts with the assumption $x \geq 2$.

Therefore, the answer would be $x=1.6$.

Comment: It seems to me that you looked at the graph and realized that when $x < 2$, $g(x) = x^2$ rather than computing it the way you claimed you did.  If $g(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, knowing that $g(0) = 0 \implies c = 0 \implies g(x) = ax^2 + bx$.  Therefore, knowing that $g(2) = 4 \implies 4a + 2b = 4$.  It does not tell you the values of $a$ and $b$.  For that, you either need a third point on the graph or have to use the equation $g(x) = a(x - h)^2 + k$ and the fact that the vertex $(h, k) = (0, 0)$.  After that, your explanation is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You should graph $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x - 2.4$ on the same axes.  Recall that $0 < \mathrm{e}^x \leq 1$ for $x \leq 0$, so $f$ and $g$ have no intersection for $x \leq 0$.  $\mathrm{e}^x$ continues to increase as we go to the right.  For $x = 1$, $\mathrm{e}^1 \approx 2.7$, so $f(1) \approx 0.3$ and we can see $g(1) = 1$, so $f$ has not increased enough to catch up with $g$.  $\mathrm{e}^2 - 2.4 \approx 5$, so $f$ has passed $g$.  Then it is a matter of searching between $1$ and $2$ for an interval like $[1.4,1.5]$ where $f$ is the lesser on the left and $g$ is the lesser on the right.  (Note:  "1.4" may not be the left endpoint, this is only an example of the sort of interval you want.)  I'd make a table of $f$ and $g$ values in that interval.  (It's relatively clear that $g$ is approximately $x^2$ on $[-2,2]$.)